# Why clip_roi function in lidR only work with SpatialPolygons and not SpatVector?

Tags: lidr

Most of the functions from `lidR` work using `SpatVector` and `SpatRaster` from `terra` package but I obtained this error using `clip_roi` function

```
Error in clip_roi(ctg, Extent1) : Geometry type SpatVector not supported
```

This is a bug? or something have to improve to make compatible `clip_roi` and package `terra`?.

Comment: `lidR` works with `Raster`, `SpatRaster` and `stars`  but none of the function accept or return `SpatVector`. It only works with `sf`.

Comment: Thank you JRR. I appreciate the reply since I am trying to move to work only with terra package I did not notice this detail. Sorry for the inconvenience